# Bootstrap Modal Plugin Loading Not Displaying

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've racked my brain for hours and I can't figure out why bootstrap modal won't show the loading screen from inside a .on event when using it's ajax functionality. The $('body').modalmanager('loading'); works if I put it outside the .on event, so I know the scripts are working properly. But when it's inside the on event, just like in the plugin examples, I get nothing. Any suggestions?

I'm binding a click event using the code below:

```
    $.fn.modalmanager.defaults.resize = true;
    $.fn.modalmanager.defaults.spinner = '<div class="loading-spinner fade" style="width: 200px; margin-left: -100px;"><img src="http://localhost:2621/assets/img/ajax-modal-loading.gif" align="middle">&nbsp;<span style="font-weight:300; color: #eee; font-size: 18px; font-family:Open Sans;">&nbsp;Loading...</div>';

var $modal = $('#add-offense');

$('.add-offense-btn').on('click', function () {
    // create the backdrop and wait for next modal to be triggered
    // THIS IS NEVER CALLED INSIDE THE .on EVENT
    $('body').modalmanager('loading');

    var url = "/case/saveoffense/"; // the url to the controller

    setTimeout(function () {
        $modal.load(url, '', function () {

            $modal.modal().on("hidden", function () {
                $modal.empty();
            });
            $modal.modal();
        })
    }, 1000);
});
```

And in addition to bootstrap.js, I'm including the latest bootstrap-modal files seen below:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modal.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Comment: Any chance you can throw it up on jsbin?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't paste in the exact js code. I have found that the $('body').modalmanager('loading') is being made, but the load functionality just fails, even using the exact code from the plugin demo. I'm guessing I have an id or css class conflict?

Answer (score -1):

See the a tag; use instead of href=''